# JavaFX 2.2.21 - moving objects only inside of VBOX or HBOX

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I'm using *GridPane* to place 3 boxes where i draw different animation. How could i do that this animated objects wouldn't be visible outside of this boxes? Or should i use something other where to draw objects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the clip property of each of the boxes:

```
final Rectangle firstClippingRectangleNode = new Rectangle(64.0, 64.0, 64.0, 64.0);
firstBox.setClip(firstClippingRectangleNode);
```

Further information can be found in the [JavaFX 2 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html).

Good luck!